# how to add a new column to each dataset in a list

Tags: r

I have looked at some similar questions but they haven't really helped.

I have a list with 4 datasframes and I would like to add a column to each of the 4 dataframes.

below are a few of the commands that I've tried.
they all just result in a list of 4 vectors (just the diversity).

```
abundance_tables<-lapply(abundance_tables,function(tab) tab$diversity<-diversity(tab) )
abundance_tables<-mapply(function(tab) tab$diversity<-diversity(tab),abundance_tables,SIMPLIFY = F )
```

any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide sample data, so I'm generating a sample `list` of 4 `data.frame`s.

```
lst <- lapply(1:4, function(x) data.frame(one = LETTERS[1:4], two = 1:4))
```

We add a third column to every `data.frame` in the `list`.

```
lapply(lst, function(x) { x$three = letters[11:14]; x })
#[[1]]
#  one two three
#1   A   1     k
#2   B   2     l
#3   C   3     m
#4   D   4     n
#
#[[2]]
#  one two three
#1   A   1     k
#2   B   2     l
#3   C   3     m
#4   D   4     n
#
#[[3]]
#  one two three
#1   A   1     k
#2   B   2     l
#3   C   3     m
#4   D   4     n
#
#[[4]]
#  one two three
#1   A   1     k
#2   B   2     l
#3   C   3     m
#4   D   4     n
```

Note that we need to return `x`, to get the `data.frame` with the added column.

Comment: great. thanks  that worked.  I didn't know that we had to return x

Comment: Or `lapply(lst, cbind, three=letters[11:14])` if you want to avoid the anonymous function.